# How I can define a weight matrix for a certain model?

Tags: algorithms

I'm trying to develop a deep learning implementation in Python to learn how the math behind it works. I've seen a lot of tutorials and they define weight matrices with different sizes(2x2, 3x3, 4x3 ....). How can I define a matrix size for a certain type of model?

The model I'm replicating is a linear model. So it's basics are:

```
w1*x1 + w2*x2 + w3*x3 ...
```

Comment: Wee [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) on numpy how to create a n-dimensional matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Depends completely on the kind of network you are building, what kind and how much data you have. For the sake of simplicity, lets talk about a network with just one hidden layer and binary output. Then the weight matrix for your hidden layer will be input dimension x hidden dimension where dimension is the number of units i.e.features. Then to convert your hidden features into the two outputs, you need a set of weights of the size hidden dimension x 2. If you want to know how many layers and how many units you should use, thats quite a vast topic. Here is a SO question that might help with that [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw)